# Decrease Noise from DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, flyback, decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

[image: Simple Motor Configuration]

I have a 9v battery pack and a small dc motor connected according to the diagram above.

When the motor is disconnected my battery terminals have a peak-to-peak voltage of 800mv:

[image: Normal Voltage]

However, during motor operation, my battery voltage can fluctuate as much as 9.4v peak-to-peak, which, by no coincidence, is equal to Vmax of the supply with no motor:

[image: Spiky Voltage]

How can I reduce this this noise and bring it down to a reasonable level? I understand this question has been asked several times before, but I want to achieve a more abstract approach for any motor, given a set of characteristics.

I am aware of the following techniques, none of which have been implemented:

1. Add a capacitor across the supply to suppress base fluctuations
2. Use capacitor(s) to decouple the motor from the rest of the circuit
3. Add flyback diodes to short away any back-emf from the inductive load

**Bonus**

Say I wanted to clean up the spiky voltage on a 60v supply driving a more powerful motor. How would the values of each helper element change, if at all?

Comment: 1. and 2. are essentially identical. Further than that, no general advice can be given – it depends on the motor, your voltage source, and your *specific* (in)tolerance for noise.

Comment: I don't see why a 9 V battery without load would exhibit 800 mV p-p voltage. Unsuitable measurement technique?

Comment: @Anders Petersson if it helps, it is six 1.5v batteries in series.

Comment: @AndersPetersson probably EMI picked up by the wires, some of it possibly coming from the scope itself. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: what about adding an inductor?

Comment: where is the scope Ground connected?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf right at the battery negative terminal, as indicated in the schematic...